# Using the current year instead of hardcording it in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date-arithmetic

Here's a correct and working statement:

```
SELECT purch_id AS PURCH_ID
       ,TO_DATE('25-DEC-12') - purch_date AS DAYS_TO_CHRISTMAS
FROM CS260USER.candy_purchase;
```

I'd like to modify it so that instead of hard-coding 2012 (or, 12) at the end of the expression, I'd like it to grab the current system year and slap that sucker on the end.

Thoughts?

Comment: [SYSDATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm) function returns you current server date.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT purch_id AS PURCH_ID,
       (trunc(sysdate,'yyyy') +
          interval '11' month +
          interval '24' day) - purch_date AS DAYS_TO_CHRISTMAS
  FROM CS260USER.candy_purchase;
```

will work.  You could also do it via string manipulation

```
SELECT purch_id AS PURCH_ID,
       to_date( '12-25-' || to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'), 'mm-dd-yyyy') 
         - purch_date AS DAYS_TO_CHRISTMAS
  FROM CS260USER.candy_purchase;
```

I prefer to do date manipulation on dates and string manipulation on strings though string manipulation might be clearer here.